# Relationship Classes with existing data in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, relationship-class

I'm new to ArcGIS Online and am still getting used to the terminology, but GIS is not new to me at all; I'm always learning. I've recently migrated my work's GIS data to ArcGIS Online using ArcGIS Pro to launch it. GlobalIDs have been assigned to everything. There are a couple feature layers that each contain from 600 to 2200 features, each of which have multiple attachments. Each feature layer has been customized in multiple maps and they are already employed in several apps and dashboards that have been dispersed company-wide. These feature layers are the backbone of my work's GIS and most future tasks will be built upon them.

Those future tasks include merging multiple maintenance records in CSV form (no geographical data, but do contain IDs that are common with feature classes that do) to those existing feature layers and developing web apps so data can be entered from the field. That data in return will be monitored by dashboards and other apps.

I know that the ideal way to set this up would be to merge all the data while in the GBD, but that ship has seemingly sailed (unless the only way to do this is to download the data, then merge or create relationship classes, and reupload but overwriting would scramble a lot of customization) and I am under the understanding that merging isn't doable in AGOL.

Is it still possible to create Relationship Classes there?

Everything I've seen so far has the relationship set up locally, then uploaded. I find that a tad difficult to allow for future expansion and tasks related to the parent dataset.

If I could create Relationship Classes with existing Online data without unraveling what I've built, that would be perfect. This is more of a conceptual thing; I'm not looking for my hand to be held via step-by-step, but like I said I'm still new to this facet of GIS and could use some guidance or suggestions.

Comment: Have you searched GIS SE, [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/270670/related-tables-in-arcgis-online) came up? There are many other Q&A about relationships.

Comment: I have searched, but everything I've seen has the Relationship Class established before uploading to ArcGIS Online. My geodatasets have already been uploaded and are being used, but the tables I'm looking to link with them are not. I'm wondering if there is a way to do this Online, or am I forced to download the geodataset, establish the relationship class, and overwrite the geodataset in AGOL while hoping my work there doesn't get shredded?

Comment: Check out: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000025302 (probably not the answer you're looking for)